# How can I access Spring bean from Message-driven bean in JBoss AS 7

Tags: spring, ejb, jboss7.x

I want to make a call to a Spring bean (a @Component) from my message-driven bean (MDB) but have problems getting a reference to it. I've tried with a class implementing `org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware` which stores the Spring ApplicationContext in a static field in a class `MyAppContext`. The static field in `MyAppContext` is then accessed from the MDB. But `MyAppContext` is loaded from different classloaders. The Spring application context is correctly set in the web module classloader context, but in the MDB's classloader context, it's null.

Can I somehow instruct JBoss to use the same classloader for the web app and the MDB?

Or is there a better way than storing the Spring application context in a static field?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A static holder for the context is not really a good idea. To make your beans available to other applications in a Java EE environment, you should consider making use of JNDI.

Unfortunately, there is no plain JNDI exporter available out of the box, but it's fairly easy to write one yourself, as shown in this blog post: http://maestro-lab.blogspot.ro/2009/01/how-to-export-spring-managed-bean-to.html

There is however a [JndiRmiServiceExporter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/remoting/rmi/JndiRmiServiceExporter.html) that you may want to look at.

Once your beans are bound to names in JNDI, they can be referenced using standard CDI in your message bean without worrying about class loading issues.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use "ClassPathXmlApplicationContext" to load and look up for the Spring bean you require in your MBean?